# IF Isblank Formula giving an error

Tags: excel

I have the formula and it is giving an error "You have entered too many argumants"

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Sheet2'!A1,"",'Sheet2'!A1)
```

Comment: You are missing the `)` after the first `'Sheet2'!A1`

Answer (score 0):

ISBLANK checks if an entry is blank, so it only takes the entry as an argument. You need to close the ISBLANK statement before Excel can continue with the rest of the if.

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Sheet2'!A1),"",'Sheet2'!A1)
```

Comment: However seeing what you're trying to achieve, wouldn't simply `='Sheet2'!A1` be sufficient since you're saying "If A1 of Sheet2 is blank replace it with a blank, otherwise fill it with the value found in A1 of Sheet2"?

Comment: I actually want to replace it with something else

Comment: Ok, then you have the right format, just edit the if statement accordingly. Also, on Stack Overflow, the appropriate way to thank someone is to mark their answer as correct and/or upvote it if you can. Comments are supposed to be used principally for clarifications or adding additional information, but they aren't to be used like a message board with "thanks" or any such "chat" like responses. Good luck with your excel!